# Adding a variable to tiptip jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tiptip

I couldn't think of a more descriptive title, so I do hope it makes sense (feel free to correct me if I am wrong).

Basically I am adding tables to a site and the columns will automatically resize according to the amount of columns being added.
Adding a single works perfectly well, where it's getting a bit complicated for me (perhaps over the head) is as soon as I add an additional table on the same page - the script which runs counts all of the columns in their entirety.
For instance, if I add a three column table at the top of the page then and additional three column table at the bottom - the script then counts a total of 6 columns then divides 100 by that number..

Is there a simple way to create a variable or a table count so that the script at the bottom detects separate tables and resizes the columns per table?

Snippets of the code below:

```
<div class="table<?php echo $tblid; ?>">
        <div class="cols">
        </div>

    ..code going on here..
        <div class="cols">
        </div> 
    ..Some more code going on here..
</div>
```

```
    var v = jQuery('.table .cols').length;

    var cw = (100/v);

    jQuery('.table .cols').css('width',cw+'%');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am not wrong, youu have two tables with the same classname , so your selector `jQuery('.table .cols')` gets both the table and  `jQuery('.table .cols').length;` will give you the length of the cols combining both the tables...

what you can do is.
Give them seperate class and call each one..

**HTML**

```
 <div class="table1">
    <div class="cols">
    </div>

  ..other code going on here..

</div>

<div class="table2">
    <div class="cols">
    </div>

  ..other code going on here..

</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('div[class^="table"]').each(function(){
    var obj=jQuery(this).find('.cols');
    var v = obj.length;
    var cw = (100/v);

    obj.css('width',cw+'%');
  });
});
```

this should work for any number of tables..

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response - your answer did give me some ideas, however, as is the cols div is not even being resized.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no error.  However, upon inspection the the previous script I had running injects the width into the DOM.  The one you have so kindly created, doesn't seem to be doing the same. Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: Schoolboy error there on my behalf.  Have updated accordingly.  Now I have getting an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.  Seems to be heading in the right direction at least

Comment: ok.. my bad.. i missed the brackets.. please check now it hsould wokr.. let me if any problem